# Algorithm implemented in the timeseries\resample function of Matlab

Tags: matlab, resampling

Does anyone know what algorithm is implemented in the Matlab function `resample` for **timeseries**?

I had a look on the manual but it just gives the instruction to use it: http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/resampletscollection.html

Since the syntax is different from the one used for the usual `resample` (http://it.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/resample.html) I assumed is not the same algorithm. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly edit the code with `open resample` and browse the different options. INgredients are border (zero padding, border trimming) and delay management, filter design (uniform or `firls` with `kaiser`) before the use of `upfirdn` for antialiasing. A snippet of the function's help.

```
%   Y = RESAMPLE(X,P,Q,N) uses a weighted sum of 2*N*max(1,Q/P) samples of X 
%   to compute each sample of Y.  The length of the FIR filter RESAMPLE applies
%   is proportional to N; by increasing N you will get better accuracy at the 
%   expense of a longer computation time.  If you don't specify N, RESAMPLE uses
%   N = 10 by default.  If you let N = 0, RESAMPLE performs a nearest
%   neighbor interpolation; that is, the output Y(n) is X(round((n-1)*Q/P)+1)
%   ( Y(n) = 0 if round((n-1)*Q/P)+1 > length(X) ).
%
%   Y = RESAMPLE(X,P,Q,N,BTA) uses BTA as the BETA design parameter for the 
%   Kaiser window used to design the filter.  RESAMPLE uses BTA = 5 if
%   you don't specify a value.
%
%   Y = RESAMPLE(X,P,Q,B) uses B to filter X (after upsampling) if B is a 
%   vector of filter coefficients.  RESAMPLE assumes B has odd length and
%   linear phase when compensating for the filter's delay; for even length 
%   filters, the delay is overcompensated by 1/2 sample.  For non-linear 
%   phase filters consider using UPFIRDN.
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.setinterpmethod.html 
Seems to a choice between a few fairly simple interpolation schemes. The standard resample() uses a polyphase filter interpolation which is much better for most applications.

Comment: i **know** that resample() does a better job, but the setinterpmethod link seems to indicate that it's a choice between `zoh` and `linear` with `linear` as the default.  i can't believe that resample() is that bad.

Comment: A timeseries isn't the same thing as a signal in Matlab.